# MQTT client connect: Error: Connection refused: Not authorized

Tags: server, redis, microservices, mqtt, nestjs

I have a project that uses **MQTT** and **Redis** to process message queue. Use authentication through the database with username and password.

But the username, password information is completely correct, but I get the error when client connect to MQTT. This error occurs on staging server but not on development.

I have **spent 3 days** trying to figure out the cause but have not found the reason.

Can someone help me please? I'm completely stuck. below is my MQTT authentication code

```
@MessagePattern('mqtt-auth-81DPKQnMr7bd4Op63dDB/staging')
async getNotificationsStaging(@Payload() userInfo: RedisCheckUserDto, @Ctx() context: RedisContext) {
  const channelName = context.getChannel();
  if (!channelName.includes(process.env.GIT_BRANCH)) return false;
  return this.mqttAuth(userInfo);
  return true;
}


private async mqttAuth(userInfo: RedisCheckUserDto) {
  //Sunmi app
  if (userInfo.clientId.startsWith('sunmi')) {
    const outlet = await this.outletService.findOne(userInfo.username);
    console.log(!outlet)
    if (!outlet) return false;

    const isValidPassword = userInfo.password === outlet.outletPin;
    console.log(isValidPassword)
    return isValidPassword;
  }
  return false;
}
```

this is code MQTT send to backend to authentication:

```
 if (clientId.includes('staging'))
        return await this.client
          .send('mqtt-auth-81DPKQnMr7bd4Op63dDB/staging', {
            clientId,
            username,
            password: passwordString,
          })
          .toPromise();
```

this code is connect with MQTT:

```
const _mqttClient = mqtt.connect(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MQTT_URL, {
      clientId: `sunmi-${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV}-${randomId}-${outletId}`,
      username: codeName,
      password: outletPin,
    });
```

someone please help me, I'm really stuck!!!